# jest not implemented window.alert()

Tags: reactjs, api, unit-testing, jestjs

I have written a test for my API with jest. I added a function that calls my API in the test file as below:

```
import AuthManager from "../Client/Modules/Auth/AuthManager";
```

and use it as below:

```
test("login api resolves true", () => {
  return expect(AuthManager.login("test", "test")).resolves.toMatchObject(
    expect.objectContaining({
      accessToken: expect.any(String),
      email: expect.any(String),
      expiresIn: expect.any(Number),
      refreshToken: expect.any(String),
      userFullName: expect.any(String),
      userId: expect.any(Number)
    })
  );
});
```

My test passes, but I have an error as below:

> Error: Not implemented: window.alert

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [default test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) for `Jest` is a browser-like environment provided by `jsdom`.

`jsdom` implements most of what an actual browser would provide (including the global `window` object), but it doesn't implement everything.

Specifically for this case, `jsdom` does not implement `window.alert`, and instead throws an `Error` when it is called as can be seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/b83783da63deeb7c5602b024a92e214df423a412/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L611).

---

As long as you know why your code is launching the `alert` and know that your test is working properly aside from the `Error` then you can suppress the `Error` by providing an empty implementation for `window.alert`:

```
test("login api resolves true", () => {
  const jsdomAlert = window.alert;  // remember the jsdom alert
  window.alert = () => {};  // provide an empty implementation for window.alert
  return expect(AuthManager.login("test", "test")).resolves.toMatchObject(
    expect.objectContaining({
      accessToken: expect.any(String),
      email: expect.any(String),
      expiresIn: expect.any(Number),
      refreshToken: expect.any(String),
      userFullName: expect.any(String),
      userId: expect.any(Number)
    })
  );  // SUCCESS
  window.alert = jsdomAlert;  // restore the jsdom alert
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it didn't work for me as I still get the not implemented error

Comment: @dcp You've gotta mock it properly using `jest.fn`, e.g. `window.alert = jest.fn(() => ({}));` ;)

Comment: @GlennMohammad `window.alert` [doesn't return anything](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert) so if you want to use a `Jest` mock function it would just be `window.alert = jest.fn();`

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Right, thank you for the correction. I must have been daydreaming 

Answer (score 38):

How I solved this problem is actually define the `window.alert` method at the top of the test file as a jest spy. This should work for any window method (in my case I was actually testing `window.open`).

Be sure to call `mockClear()` in your test, since this is a global object and it's calls will persist across tests.

```
window.alert = jest.fn();

test("login api resolves true", () => {
  window.alert.mockClear();
  /* ... */
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but for testing the `window.print` method.

In my case, it was a matter of hoisting

```
jest.spyOn(window, 'print');
```

from the it block to below the describe block.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with `window.confirm`
This is my solution for angular fw.

```
let spyOnWindow: jasmine.Spy;

beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [...]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      ...
      spyOnWindow = spyOn(window,'confirm');
      ...
    });
```

Some test case

```
it('showModal testing function with delete an event', () => {
spyOnWindow.and.returnValue(true);
...
}

it('showModal testing function with delete an event', () => {
spyOnWindow.and.returnValue(false);
...
}
```