# Jest mock window.scrollTo

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, jsdom

My React component calls `window.scrollTo` and when I run my jest tests, they pass, but there is a console error:

```
 console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo
    at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
    at Window.scrollTo (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:544:7)
    at scrollTo (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/back-end/utils/library.jsx:180:12)
    at commitHookEffectList (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17283:26)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17307:3)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:74:10)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:256:31)
    at commitPassiveEffects (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18774:9)
    at wrapped (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler-tracing.development.js:207:34)
    at flushPassiveEffects (/private/var/www/samplesite.com/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18822:5) undefined
```

I have tried mocking it in a few ways (both in the test itself and also in a jest `setupFiles` that gets called before each test) , but the console error will not go away:

Attempt 1:

```
let window = {};
window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
```

Attempt 2:

```
let scrollTo = jest.fn();
Object.defineProperty(window, "scrollTo", scrollTo);
```

Attempt 3:

```
delete global.window.scrollTo;
global.window.scrollTo = () => {};
```

Attempt 4:

```
global.window = {};
global.window.scrollTo = () => {};
```

How can i get rid of this console error?  Thanks.

Comment: `try { } catch (err) {}` ?

Comment: I shouldn't have to put a `try/catch` in my production code to satisfy Jest, should I?

Comment: Try adding `window.scrollTo = {}` in the jest function itself (Don't define `window` on the previous line): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55092363/4875631

Comment: Adding `window.scrollTo = () => {}` in the jest function DOES work. I'd like to do this only once (in the file included Jest's `setupFiles` config), but putting the code in there does NOT work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't :(

Comment: I can put this in the `beforeEach` in the test file, but would have to repeat this in every file. A bit better than having to do it in every test. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

For me, mock `window.scrollTo` in each test case. Or, put the mock code into a `window.setup.js` file and add the path of this file into jest `setupFiles` configuration, both of these two ways work fine.

For example,

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.tsx`, mock `window.scrollTo` in each test case.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SomeComponent from './';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  test('should handle click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
    const mEvent = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click', mEvent);
    expect(mEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalled();
    expect(window.scrollTo).toBeCalledWith(0, 0);
  });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  // setupFiles: ['/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58585527/window.setup.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16'
  },
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'lcov', 'clover']
};
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58585527/index.spec.tsx (6.114s)
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should handle click (12ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.947s
```

Or, create a `window.setup.js` file and put the path of the file in jest `setupFiles`:

`window.setup.js`:

```
window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFiles: ['/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58585527/window.setup.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16'
  },
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'lcov', 'clover']
};
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58585527/index.spec.tsx
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should handle click (12ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.33s, estimated 7s
```

Both of them work fine.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58585527

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  When I put `window.scrollTo = () => {};` in window.setup.js and include it in jest.config.js (under `setupFiles`) when I run my tests I get the error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.  If I first declare `let window = {}`, the tests pass but I get the original `Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo` error.

Note that I am not testing if `window.scrollTo` is called, I dont care about that, that just happens to occur on the page I am testing.

Answer (score 1):

Setting 
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
should be working and if you want to define it for the entire project instead of each test file separately you can define it in [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array)

Or when using react-scripts you can define it in ./src/setupTests.js

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When I put `window.scrollTo = jest.fn()`; in window.setup.js and include it in jest.config.js (under `setupFilesAfterEnv`) when I run my tests I get the error: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. If I first declare `let window = {}`, the tests pass but I get the original `Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo` error. Note that I am not testing if `window.scrollTo` is called, I dont care about that, that just happens to occur on the page I am testing.

Comment: You should use `global.scrollTo` not `window.scrollTo` since jest has no window in the test runner