# Not implemeted window errors in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

I'm testing a very basic counter example element built with Redux. Here's my test:

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "src/testUtils";
import { Counter } from "../Counter";

describe("Counter screen", () => {
  it("buttons should change displayed value", () => {
    render(<Counter />);
    const counter = screen.getByText(/counter*/i);
    const plus = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /\+/i });
    const minus = screen.getByText(/\-/i);

    expect(counter).toHaveTextContent("0");
    userEvent.click(plus);
    userEvent.click(plus);
    expect(counter).toHaveTextContent("10");
    userEvent.click(minus);
    expect(counter).toHaveTextContent("9");
  });
});
```

The tests are all passing but I get a large amount of errors from `jsdom` logged to the console:

```
Error: Not implemented: window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)
          at module.exports (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
          at Window.getComputedStyle (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:657:7)
          at computeMiscTextAlternative (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:306:62)
          at computeTextAlternative (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:521:11)
          at computeAccessibleName (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:552:3)
          at /home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/role.js:72:82
          at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
          at queryAllByRole (/home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/role.js:66:6)
          at /home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:68:17
          at /home/abhijeet/Documents/github/react-template/node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:54:17 undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at module.exports (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:12:26)
      at Window.getComputedStyle (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:657:7)
      at computeMiscTextAlternative (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:306:62)
      at computeTextAlternative (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:521:11)
      at computeAccessibleName (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/dom-accessibility-api/sources/accessible-name.ts:552:3)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/role.js:72:82

    console.error
      Error: Not implemented: window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)
    ...

      Error: Not implemented: window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)
    ...

      Error: Not implemented: window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)
    ...
```

I can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55092363/7435656) that providing some fake implementation can help suppress these errors. But that just feels like a workaround/hack because I don't want to include code in tests that has nothing to do with my test logic.

Am I doing something wrong to trigger these warnings?

Packages:

```
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.28.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
```

Here's the component I'm testing from the [source code](https://github.com/cseas/react-template/blob/master/src/Counter/__tests__/Counter.test.tsx):

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { counterSlice } from "../reducers";
type CounterState = {
  counter: number;
};
export function Counter() {
  const counter = useSelector((state: CounterState) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
       <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(counterSlice.actions.decrement())}>
        -
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(counterSlice.actions.increment(5))}>
        +
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show the component code and where do you use `window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)`

Comment: I don't think I've used it anywhere in the application, unless it has something to do with redux toolkit implementation internally. Anyway, I've edited the question with the code for the component I'm testing with a link to the full source code.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67194337/8068625

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone else already has an up-to-date version, I solved this issue by upgrading my `@testing-library/react`. Not sure which version fixes it, but I went from `10.0.2` to `10.4.9`

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it by upgrading `testing-library/dom` version, as said [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/774#issuecomment-702574312).

The point is they say that upgrading to version `7.22.1` would stop showing these messages, but your `testing-library/dom` is `^7.28.1`.

My upgrade went from `7.21.4` to `7.29.1`.