# @testing-library/dom window.getComputedStyle "Not implemented" error even after setting computedStyleSupportsPseudoElements: true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsdom, ts-jest

I'm using jest to test a custom module that implements react embla carousel.

I received an error related to jsdom lacking an implementation for `window.getComputedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)`

```
Error: Not implemented: window.computedStyle(elt, pseudoElt)
```

After a bit of searching I found out that the second parameter wasn't supported by jsdom and the wonderful folks at `@testing-library` had an option to do... something... about it.

**Reference**

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration#computedstylesupportspseudoelements

**jest-setup.js:**

```
import { configure } from '@testing-library/dom';
configure({
  computedStyleSupportsPseudoElements: true
})
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Unfortunately though, this doesn't seem to fix my error. I know the configuration is being applied because I set some other configuration options that broke all my tests.

Am I not applying something correctly or is there potentially another workaround? I don't need the full functionality of the carousel in the test I just want to make sure the data I pass to the view is being rendered properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same error when updating Jest to the latest version (26.6.3). [Calling  **getComputedStyle** as a window property](https://github.com/davidcetinkaya/embla-carousel/commit/f903ed5f8da95bca7cec72f125801ae2a7fada5c#diff-0578de2d409c1ec5b0b9590d33e050981849d194ea7fd72a04fadefd11d33f2bL8) in the `embla-carousel` code was causing this issue for me:

```js
const pseudoString = window.getComputedStyle(node, ':before').content
```

I also tried to solve this using the `@testing-library/dom` to no avail. But when I removed window and called **getComputedStyle** directly the issue went away:

```js
const pseudoString = getComputedStyle(node, ':before').content
```

I've released [embla-carousel](https://github.com/davidcetinkaya/embla-carousel) v4.4.1 which [includes a fix](https://github.com/davidcetinkaya/embla-carousel/commit/f903ed5f8da95bca7cec72f125801ae2a7fada5c) for this issue. Please install this version and the issue should go away.

Comment: Thank you! The best kind of answer, I'll update today :)