# React testing library only works for inline styles

Tags: css, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test if an element has the proper styles. However this only works when I add inline styling to the element. I'm also using css modules, so I'm not sure if that is the problem.
The test

```
test("3.1.2.if the nav link opens properly", () => {
  render(
    <Router>
      <Header />
    </Router>
  );
  const nav = screen.getByRole("navigation");
  expect(nav.style).toHaveProperty("transform", "rotate(0)")
});
```

(Relevant) JSX

```
<div
          className={`${styles.options} ${
            dropdownOpened ? styles.options__dropdown__open : ""
          }`}
          onClick={handleDropdown}
          role="navigation"
        >
          <IconContext.Provider
            value={{
              color: "white",
              className: styles.options__dropdown__btn,
            }}
          >
            <IoMdArrowDropdown />
          </IconContext.Provider>
        </div>
```

(Relevant) CSS

```
.options:not(.options__menu__opened, .options__dropdown__open) {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), see also [@testing-library/dom window.getComputedStyle "Not implemented" error even after setting computedStyleSupportsPseudoElements: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912897/testing-library-dom-window-getcomputedstyle-not-implemented-error-even-after)